# Generate JSON based off Logic App Inputs every time a change is made

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a Mongo collection which contains a JSON representation of each "Service" I create. These services were created using Azure Functions in which I used annotations to allow the user to add metadata needed in the JSON. At compile time, those annotations were read and the JSON file was generated and sent to Mongo.

Now, I would like to create services using Logic Apps. In my UI, I specify the parameters I want my Logic App to take and then generate a starter workflow for the user. The goal is for the user to develop their Logic App and then when it's ready, there will be some way to trigger the JSON to be generated and sent to Mongo. The JSON needs to contain the input parameters and then some extra meta data for each input (Ui properties such as description, default value, type etc). So essentially there are two problems I am trying to solve:

1. Where do I add metadata to each parameter?
   I thought there would be some way to define a custom parameter in a Logic App which would prompt the user to enter all the meta data needed for that parameter. Then the inputs could be used to generate the JSON.
2. Every time a Logic App is created/updated, I would like it to generate the updated JSON and send that to Mongo. Is there a way to trigger some code every time the Logic App is updated?

I'm not sure if that was very clear but any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried doing this? If so, what are the errors or blockers you are facing?

Comment: Yes, I have managed to setup an Event Grid which watches the resource group containing my Logic App. From there I am able to pick up when the Logic App is saved so I can use that as my trigger for sending the JSON to Mongo. Now I am just stuck trying to generate the JSON itself from the input parameters. Ideally, I want a custom input parameters screen in the Logic App itself where I can specify the input parameter and any extra meta data for that parameter needed in my JSON.